# Oracle question: Problem improving conventional path load, direct=false, with number of commits and bindsize/readsize

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, bulk, sql-loader

I'm currently doing an academic benchmark, TPC-H, and I have some big tables that I want to load using direct path (which workde great and was very fast) and conventional path.

For that, I used this batch script:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in (table4_records.txt) do (
sqlldr userid='tpch/tpch' control=%%A.ctl rows=%%B bindsize=? readsize=? SILENT=HEADER log=bulkload_logs\sf4\bulk_%%A%1.log
)
```

The problem is that, no matter what values I give to the bindsize and/or readsize options, it always commit from 65534 to 65534 rows. I already pass the %%B size which is the exactly number of rows per table.

In direct load, I just used the rows and the commit as REALLY done after the hole table was loaded.

I want to do something like that, but with conventional load path - I know that is not faster, but that's the point.

Could you please tell me how can I give the correct parameters so I can:
1- load as much data, at a time, as I can;
2- commit less frequently, preferably at the end of the table's load.

Here are the tables' names and number of rows:

lineitem 23996604 -> is the biggest and has aprox. 3GB on disk
orders 6000000
partsupp 3200000
part 800000
customer 600000
supplier 40000
nation 25
region 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops:

It turns out ROWS maximum number, in Conventional Path, is 65534 exactly, so I could keep increasing my bindarray size! LOL

Sorry, I've just found it in Oracle's documentation

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a 3GB file to use a conventional path load and commit at the end.
From the Oracle docs:

"When SQL*Loader sends the Oracle database an INSERT command, the entire array is inserted at one time. After the rows in the bind array are inserted, a COMMIT statement is issued."

"In the conventional path method, the bind array is limited by the size of the read buffer. Therefore, the advantage of a larger read buffer is that more data can be read before a commit operation is required."

Maximise the READSIZE and BINDSIZE until it tells you that you've hit the maximum for your platform.

Answer (score -1):

Burleson's site has [a possible way to do this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_loader_commit_frequency.htm).

Comment: It doesn't work. I really tried a lot of values to bindsize, readsize, one or another or both. I never could get the sql loader to commit only at the end of the table.